# Laying out controls with XAMARIN Flexlayout

Tags: c#, xamarin, layout

I am designing a data entry screen in XAMARIN using their new control - FlexLayout. I am trying to ensure that this data entry form will display on small screens and big screens e.g.on a small screen - each control will be one per row.  On a large screen, one row for all controls.

I am using Flexlayout which allows wrapping.  But I am having a problem with the Entry boxes.  I have 4 controls

1. Alpha Numeric box - 20 characters (Batch Number place holder)
2. Alpha Numeric box - 30 characters (Serial Number place holder)
3. Numeric box - I have this set to use the numeric keyboard so can't
   put a place holder beside it.  So I have to put a label beside this
   box.
4. Data Picker - I have to put a label beside this box too

I have tried various properties belonging to the FlexLayout.  All of the samples online that I can find relate to labels and images which I can get to work the way I want my Entry controls to work.

```
  <FlexLayout Direction="Row" 
    AlignItems="Start" 
     AlignContent="Start" 
     JustifyContent="SpaceAround"  
       Wrap="Wrap" >
   <Entry Placeholder="Batch Number" FlexLayout.Grow="1"/>
   <Entry Placeholder="Serial Number" FlexLayout.Grow="1"/>
   <Label Text="Quantity" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
    <Entry Keyboard="Numeric" FlexLayout.Grow="1" />
    <Label Text="Purchased"  VerticalOptions="Center"  />
    <DatePicker  IsEnabled="False"  />
    </FlexLayout>
```

I get the Entry boxes with about size for two characters. I tried Flexlayout.Grow="1" but it doesn't make any difference. I was also trying to get the labels beside the "Quantity" and the date picker field to be centered beside the entry and date picker controls but that's not working either.

Any help - much appreciated.

Ann

Edited:

This is what I would like if the screen size allowed - alternatively if it was a small screen, each of the controls would be on their own line.

[image: pic 1 - ideal]

What I am getting is

[image: pic 2 - what i'm getting]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot about what effect do you want?

Comment: Added images above - the first is just one I did in Paint because I can't get what I want in Xamarin.

Comment: Why did you use FlexLayout?If you want to implment it ,I suggest that you can use grid.

Comment: The grid forces me to specify row and column which is fine if the screen size doesn't change.  But if I have a small mobile screen, I want each entry box on a separate row whereas if I have a large screen, I want them on one line.  Or on a mid size screen, two entry controls on one row and the other two on the next row.  You can't do that on a grid - or if you can, I don't know how!

Comment: Set the `JustifyContent` as start .Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.flexlayout.justifycontent?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  I tried the JustifyContent and no luck.  I posted the question in Xamarin Forums and one of the respondents said he found FlexLayout a bit "unfinished".  I've gone back to a grid layout for now.